# working navigation but toggle does not open

Tags: html, css, navigation, toggle

After nearly a week I am still struggling with toggle on navigation. 
This is my current CSS, what I need to do now, is simply get the toggle to open, it did open before so something minor is stopping it now but I cant work it out. I do not really know much about CSS as I keep forgetting it, but I do not know javascript or jquery

````css
  .nav {
  background-color: #3333FF;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu label,
#hamburger {
  display: none;
}

.menu ul {
  font-family: Monserrat, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu ul li {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 11.11%;
}

.menu ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu li:visited {
  background: #0000EE;
  color: #fff;
}

.menu li:active,
.active {
  background: #0000EE;
  color: #fff;
}

.menu li:hover {
  background: #0000EE;
  color: #fff;
}

label {
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 44px;
  display: none;
}

#toggle {
  display: none;
}


/* Show Hamburger */

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .nav {
    background-color: #3333FF;
    width: 100%;
  }
  ``` .menu label {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #3333FF;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
  }
  .menu ul {
    display: none;
  }
  .menu ul li {
    display: block;
    border-top: 1px solid #333;
  }
  .menu ul li:active {
    display: block;
  }
  .menu label {
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 44px;
    display: block;
  }
  #toggle:checked+.menu {
    display: block;
  }
````

```html
<div class="nav">
  <div class="menu">
    <label for="toggle">&#9776;</label><input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href=" http://news.html">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://contacts.html">Contacts</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://policies.html">Policies</a></li>
      <li class="active"><a href="http://members.html">Members</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://volunteer.html">Volunteer</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://links.html">Links</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your selector from:

```
#toggle:checked+.menu {
    display: block;
}
```

to:

```
#toggle:checked+ ul {
   display: block;
}
```

See snippets below:

```css
.nav {
  background-color: #3333FF;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu label,
#hamburger {
  display: none;
}

.menu ul {
  font-family: Monserrat, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu ul li {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 11.11%;
}

.menu ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu li:visited {
  background: #0000EE;
  color: #fff;
}

.menu li:active,
.active {
  background: #0000EE;
  color: #fff;
}

.menu li:hover {
  background: #0000EE;
  color: #fff;
}

label {
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 44px;
  display: none;
}

#toggle {
  display: none;
}


/* Show Hamburger */

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .nav {
    background-color: #3333FF;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .menu label {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #3333FF;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
  }
  .menu ul {
    display: none;
  }
  .menu ul li {
    display: block;
    border-top: 1px solid #333;
  }
  .menu ul li:active {
    display: block;
  }
  .menu label {
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 44px;
    display: block;
  }
  #toggle:checked+ul {
    display: block;
  }
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <div class="menu">
    <label for="toggle">&#9776;</label><input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href=" http://news.html">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://contacts.html">Contacts</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://policies.html">Policies</a></li>
      <li class="active"><a href="http://members.html">Members</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://volunteer.html">Volunteer</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://links.html">Links</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Trie your method, but it is not even showing the hamburger so it does not work

Comment: By any chance, do you have screenshot of your output? So far, this is working on my end, even you try the code snippet included on my answer, see https://snipboard.io/J0enbc.jpg

Comment: Thankyou I do have it working now. Like your snip as the links are on the left and looks good.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for this. You can try this code. It is fully tested. I hope it will help you. You can change colors and backgrounds as per needed in this code.

```css
nav ul ul {
  display: none;
}
nav ul ul li {
  float: none;
}
nav li {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
}
nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px 20px 5px 0;
  padding: 8px 10px;
}
nav li a:link, nav li a:visited {
  color: #646565;
  background: #e8e9eb;
}
nav li a:link:hover, nav li a:visited:hover {
  color: black;
}
nav li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}

input.toggle,
label.toggle {
  display: none;
}

label.toggle {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

@media (max-width: 960px) {
nav {
  display: none;
}
input.toggle, .toggle span {
  display: none;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ nav, label.toggle {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
nav li {
  float: none;
}
nav li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
nav li ul {
  display: block;
}
nav li ul li {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
nav li a {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
}
```

```html
   

     <div class="wrapper">
        <label class="toggle" for="toggle">&#9776; <span>Menue</span></label>
        <input class="toggle" id="toggle" type="checkbox">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li class="current"><a href="http://index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href=" http://news.html">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://contacts.html">Contacts</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://policies.html">Policies</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://members.html">Members</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://volunteer.html">Volunteer</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://links.html">Links</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks I will try it but the other one did work once upon a time

Comment: That one is way off, the checkbox is showing and the links are showing all the time, vertically. Are you sure you tested it?